# QString::utf16(): Is it UB or not?

Tags: c++, qt, undefined-behavior

Let's take the following source code:

```
const ushort *QString::utf16() const
{
    if (IS_RAW_DATA(d)) {
        // ensure '\0'-termination for ::fromRawData strings
        const_cast<QString*>(this)->reallocData(uint(d->size) + 1u);
    }
    return d->data();
}
```

reallocData() modifies the d-pointer class member **d**, see https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp.html#_ZN7QString11reallocDataEjb . What if the QString object is const? According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast modifying const objects with casting away constness is UB:

```
struct type {
    int i;

    type(): i(3) {}

    void f(int v) const {
        const_cast<type*>(this)->i = v; // OK as long as the type object isn't const
    }
};

type t; // if this was const type t, then t.f(4) would be undefined behavior
t.f(4);
```

Do we have UB in this particular piece of code (QString::utf16())?

Answer (score 6):

This would indeed be an UB if `QString` object on which this method in invoked is const-qualified:

```
QString const str{"whatever"};
str.utf16();
```

Note that important part here is that object is const-qualified, not that the method is const-qualified.

Comment: This is also the reason I would qualify `d` with `mutable` instead of this `const_cast` business.

Comment: The trouble with mutable, is that you then need a mutex around every reference to the variable - even when the object is on the stack, and can't be referenced from another thread.

Comment: @rubenvb I would rather make this method non-const qualified. And probably changed name to indicate that it is transforming string to something like `ConvertToUtf16`.

Comment: @VTT well, that's an API decision. Think of accessing buffered/cached values of a calculation, same story. This type of thing is a proper use case for `mutable`.

Comment: @Martin not anymore than you would around other variables. Note the current `const_cast` isn't any better. The idea behind making this is that the creation of the cache variable is mutexed internally, but it runs only once (until the underlying object is actually altered, in which case all bets are off anyway). In any case, `QString` and most other Qt containers aren't great examples of anything really.

Comment: @rubenvb A const variable *should* be accessible from multiple threads without errors.  A mutable variable without locks breaks that. See solution to [GotW #95](https://herbsutter.com/2014/01/13/gotw-95-solution-thread-safety-and-synchronization/) (specifically 4(b))

Comment: Counter example: `QString s("whatever"); QString const& sr = s; sr.utf16();` is not UB...

Comment: @Aconcagua In your example object is not const-qualified.

Comment: @Martin yes, but the accessor (here `QString::utf16()`) can do the locking, and it will satisfy your requirements without "mutexing all references".

Comment: @rubenv **NO**!  If a variable can be modified, you need to protect *all* references to it (both reads and writes) to ensure thread safety

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behaviour if (and only if) the object in question was originally created `const`:

```
QString const sc("whatever");
sc.utf16();                  // undefined behaviour!

QString s("whatever");
QString const& scr = s;
scr.utf16();                 // NOT undefined behaviour!
```

Still, casting away constness is a *very bad* idea, as, within the function, you never know if the object in question is a true const object or is only a pointer/reference to a object originally created non-const, so there is *always* immanent danger of UB!

Best is just not having the function const:

```
const ushort* QString::utf16()
{
    //...
}
```

As the case might be, users then are forced to create a non-const copy, even if the original object actually *was* non-const, but this is always better than risking UB!